# Using Jenkins to run CI on local laptop with VirtualBox VMs

Tags: powershell, jenkins, virtualbox

I am doing local Chef dev on my Windows 8.1 laptop and use VirtualBox 5.1.24 for VMs.  I want to use Jenkins (v2.73.2) to run jobs that will automate the restoring of VM snapshots and running of kitchen converge, test and repeat.

I have added the VirtualBox Plugin but it doesn't let me add a node (I recall seeing somewhere that v2.73.2 of Jenkins is not supported).

I wrote some Powershell to do what I want and so after installing PowerShell Plugin created a pipeline with following PowerShell to test it:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" startvm "W2008_21_06_B"
```

(which works in PS ISE), but fails in Jenkins job:

```
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\vbox
[vbox] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\windows\TEMP\jenkins7025720492184266246.ps1'"
vboxmanage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'W2008_21_06_B'
vboxmanage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
vboxmanage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(pszVM).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 573 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What trick am I missing please?

Regards